# How to display 2 thumbnails of span6 per row in Bootstrap with Django?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display 2 thumbnails per row. It would be pretty trivial to just hard-code it using multiple rows and each row has 2 `span6` div's. But how would I do this in Django using a template for-loop?

*Example:*

```
{% for image in images %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">*image goes here*</div>
    <div class="span6">*image goes here*</div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

// repeat for all items in the list, with 2 images per row
```

So, in the code above `span6` should be created on every loop iteration, but the `row` should be created only every 2 iterations.

**update**: I was able to span all my `span6` elements inside a single row. I encountered an issue where thumbnails wouldn't align properly (empty spaces between rows). Setting all thumbnails to a uniform height fixed the problem. But Hedde's solution looks pretty good too, although that involves changing things on the Python side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well it could be done by css only, but if you want to use the provided grid, you could create a generator and use it on your view's queryset or directly in a template by using a tag, e.g.

```
def grouped(l, n):
    # Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
```

templatetags

```
@register.filter
def group_by(value, arg):
    return grouped(value, arg)
```

templates

```
{% for group in objects|group_by:2 %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for obj in group %}
            <div class="span6">
                foo
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do it without adding templating logic to your Python code. You do need to make sure you have an even number of items in your list, or the cycle won't close properly.

```
{% for image in images %}
  {% cycle "<div class='row'>" "" %}
    <div class="span6">*image goes here*</div>
  {% cycle "" "</div>" %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can make this work for more columns, just by adding additional blanks to the cycle templatetag. If anyone can think of a simple way to close the loop when there is an odd number of items in the list, I would love to hear it!

Comment: Old thread, but for anyone wondering how to close that last </div> whith an odd number of items in the list, try using the divisibleby filter instead of cycle.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645597/how-to-make-dynamic-content-display-across-a-grid-using-django-with-bootstrap