# django template to populate bootstrap rows and columns

Tags: django, templates, twitter-bootstrap, tags

So here's my problem: I've got a bunch of instances of a class. I would like to have a sort of table of these instance objects, so that there is a maximum of six in every row. In bootstrap terms, I would like each object to be represented by a thumbnail in a "div" of class "span2".

My initial impulse was to use a nested for loop, but I am having trouble manipulating my index variable in the template, and I can't figure out how to do so outside of my template.

Here is generally what the python/django template/pseudo code is I'm trying to figure out.

```
queryset = Class.objects.all()
set_length = queryset.count()

num_rows = set_length/6 
#because I want 6 columns in each row, each with one instance

set_as_list = list(queryset) 
# have a list so I can iterate through objects by index

for i in range(table_rows):
    # make a row
    <div class="row">
    for j in range (i*6,(i+1)*6):
        #make six or less columns
        <div class="span2">
           <p>set_as_list[j].attribute1</p>
           <p>set_as_list[j].attribute2</p>
        </div>
    </div> # end row
```

I hope this flagrant mixing of django templating language, python, and html doesn't offend anybody too badly. just trying to express the idea of what I'm trying to do. I would appreciate any help someone may be willing to offer because I've been struggling with this for days and have done quite a bit of searching for a solution both within a template and outside.

I also realise that there will be need to be a final row with the remainder of objects after the integer division.

Answer (score 70):

Have no time to explain, but I've had similar problem and until i closed this browser page here is a solution

```
{% for sub_article in articles %}
    {% if forloop.first %}<div class="row">{% endif %}
    <div class="col-xs-4">
            <a href="#">
                {{ sub_article.name }}
            </a>
        </div>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}</div><div class="row">{% endif %}
    {% if forloop.last %}</div>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Any solution for the column changing its size ? For example if you go from col-md-4 to col-sm-6 it would need to be in rows divisible by 2 when the screen size changes.

Comment: After looking about the best solution i could find for my previous comment is using bootstrap .clearfix class

Comment: It's a great  answer , but how do you implement it when you have different number of columns due to different devices size ..
col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12
Maybe add logic for divisibleby other numbers and then add the finishing tags.

Comment: @TzviGregoryKaidanov In that case divide by the the LCM of total columns. For example, `col-md-4` shows 3 columns per row, `col-sm-6` shows 2 columns per row and `col-xs-12` shows 1 column per row, the LCM of 3, 2 and 1 is 6. So use `divisibleby:6`. Similarly, if you had `col-md-3` (4 columns in a row) and `col-sm-6` (2 columns in a row), you'd use `divisibleby:4` because LCM of 4 and 2 is 4. (I know this comment is three years late, but I added this for someone else looking for answer).

Comment: @xyres i think he means to be responsive? not that you change the divisible number in loop

Answer (score 3):

Since forloop.counter starts the index with 1, divisibleby 3 does not work.
So use forloop.counter0 instead.

```
<div class="row">
{% for product in all_products %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
        </div><br><div class="row">
    {% endif %}
        <div class="col-4"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: that would insert a row every n'th iteration so between you will get elements not in the row

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to add a custom tag `as_chunk`. I think it makes the code prettier and more readable.

```
# app/templatetags/my_tags.py

from math import ceil
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def as_chunks(lst, chunk_size):
    limit = ceil(len(lst) / chunk_size)
    for idx in range(limit):
        yield lst[chunk_size * idx : chunk_size * (idx + 1)]


# app/templates/your-template.html

{% load my_tags %}

...

{% for chunk in elements|as_chunk:6 %}
  <div class="row">
    {% for element in chunk %}
      <div class="col-2">
        {{ element.name }}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}

...
```

Comment: Super useful answer IMO, and takes the logic out of the template. Also, doesn't overload the view with unnecessary logic. Nice middle ground.

Answer (score 2):

maybe too late but there is [simple solution](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width) as follow

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for product in products %}
            {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 and not forloop.first %}<div class="w-100"></div>{% endif %}
            <div class="col">{{product.title}}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the code a bit more generic. Here's the logic:

```
queryset = Class.objects.all()
set_length = queryset.count()

<div class="row">
{% for i in queryset %}
    <div class="span2">
        <p>i.attr</p>
        <p>i.attr</p>
    </div>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"6" or forloop.last %}
        </div> <!--end row-->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this solves your problem :-)

Comment: Arpit, thank you for answering! The only problem is that this code only makes one row as far as i can tell. How would you adapt this code to make as many rows as were required?

Comment: Actually, I think this may be a duplicate. I think this post has the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450124/how-to-display-2-thumbnails-of-span6-per-row-in-bootstrap-with-django?rq=1

Comment: Yep, confirmed. The above link solves the problem. It uses a helper function so that we can iterate through chunks of six in each row.

Comment: Almost there try {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"6" or forloop.first %}<div class="row">{% endif %} at the beginning of the for loop.