# Looping a certain amount of times in Django Templates

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I downloaded a free bootstrap template that I want to use to load in "Show" items. This would be fairly simple, however each set of rows are using the `<div class="row">`property. For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
         //code here
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
         //code here
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to be able to loop 3 times within a `row` then after 3 loops, generate another `row` div tag. How can I achieve this using Django tempaltes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django template to populate bootstrap rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309593/django-template-to-populate-bootstrap-rows-and-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using the `cycle` builtin for such a task as you can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle).

You could also use the `forloop.counter` variable in a list inside a [for loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for), but maybe is easier to go with the first approach because you already know the number of times you need to cycle.

Comment: This is for sure a step in the right direction. Is there a way I can use `cycle` to disable the `row` tags on cycle?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your last question.

Comment: Sorry, I read the documentation and understand it now. I guess I should've read something before I spoke! Thanks.