# Django template : How to simulate break function or while loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I got this [Custom Tag](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2093/) about breaking, continuing loop in Django template but it look like it's posted July 4, 2010 so ....

I tried to modify it but not way to make it compatible so I'am locking for solution to break the loop with a condition

**so my code** (*i'm using custom tag for range*):

```
{% range -1:3:posts_count as n %} (begin:step:stop)
   <div class="row">
       {% range 1:4 as j %}
           {% with i=n|add:j %}
               {% if  i > posts_count %}{% break %}{% endif %} ***i want this to work***
               {% with post=blogpages|index:i %}
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                       --details--
                   </div>
               {% endwith %}
           {% endwith %}
       {% endrange %}
     </div>
{% endrange %}
```

The idea is to put every 3 posts in row using bootstrap grid
if there is any other suggestion I will look for on it

**UPDATE**

I just found the answer thanks to [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) who suggest to use :

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
    <div class=whatever>
{% endif %}
        detail
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
    <div/>
{% endif %}
```

And I recommend this too : D[jango template to populate bootstrap rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309593/django-template-to-populate-bootstrap-rows-and-columns)

Comment: There's no need for any of this; use a standard for loop and break with `{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}`. There are many many questions here on exactly this.

Comment: i didn't really look for this, I was searching for general case but this is good, i will try it and update my qs