# Django: Rows with 4 elements each

Tags: python, django

I need to a grid that has 4 elements in each row. I've tried this answer:

[django template to populate bootstrap rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309593/django-template-to-populate-bootstrap-rows-and-columns)

But grid was not aligned because some of the elements names are longer than others making them not aligned:

```
<div class="row">
  {% for product in products %}
       {% if forloop.first %}<div class="row">{% endif %}
       <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="">
             <a href="{{ product.get_url }}"><img class=""
                                                  src="{{ product.image.url }}"
                                                  alt="{{ product.name }}"></a>
          </div>

          <span class="text-center">{{ product.name }}</span>
       </div>
       {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}</div>
       <div class="row">{% endif %}
       {% if forloop.last %}</div>{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Giving this result:

[image]

2) Then I've tried using Ul and li elements:

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="my_products_list list-inline">
        {% for product in products %}


            <li class="text-center list-inline-item my_margin_right">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="{{ product.get_url }}"><img class="my_image_medium"
                                                         src="{{ product.image.url }}"
                                                         alt="{{ product.name }}"></a>
                </div>

                <span>{{ product.name }}</span>

            </li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

But didn't work out and gave me this result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use bootstrap grids:

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="image-container">
               <a><img/></a>
            </div>
            <span>{{ product.name }}</span>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

You can have a max of 12, so if you set 12 in the row, then divide by 4 and set 3 for each object.