# How to distribute a list of a model into rows and colunms depending on the screen size in django?

Tags: python, django, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to break-up a list of a model into rows and colunms which I am iteriating over using a forloop.

I have tried

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
```

```
<div class="row m-3">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row mt-3">
        {% for Collection in object_list %}

        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
        <div class="row mt-3">
        {% endif %}
           <div class="col-6 col-sm-3">
               <div class="dark">
               <a>
                   <div style="background-image:url({{ Collection.img }})" class="Collection">
                       </div>
                       <h3 class="title-banner text-center">{{ Collection.Name }}</h3>
               </a>
            </div>
               </div>

{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

My poblem is like [How to display 2 thumbnails of span6 per row in Bootstrap with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450124/how-to-display-2-thumbnails-of-span6-per-row-in-bootstrap-with-django?rq=1).

But that solution doesnt suit me because it doesnt allow me to change the group-by variable from the html file. I need to be able to change it because there are only two colums on mobile devices and 4 on computers. Can somebody edit that answer(first one) and post it here so I can change that variable from the html file depending on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row m-3">
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="row mt-3">
    {% for Collection in object_list %}

    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:4 %}
    <div class="row mt-3">
    {% endif %}
       <div class="col-6 col-sm-3">
           <div class="dark">
           <a>
               <div style="background-image:url({{ Collection.img }})" class="Collection">
                   </div>
                   <h3 class="title-banner text-center">{{ Collection.Name }}</h3>
           </a>
        </div>
           </div>
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [slice() filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#slice) provided by jinja2:

Considering your code:

```
<div class="row m-3">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row mt-3">
        {% for Collection in object_list|slice(4) %}
           <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 {{ loop.index }}">
               {% for item in column %}
               <div class="dark">
               <a>
                   <div style="background-image:url({{ Collection.img }})" class="Collection"></div>
                   <h3 class="title-banner text-center">{{ Collection.Name }}</h3>
               </a>
            </div>
               {% endfor %}
               </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also look at the [batch filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#batch), which allows you to manage the missing element of your last column.

Comment: how can I change the variable in slice() depending on screen size

Comment: For this needs, you can use [django-user_agents](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents) in your template in order to detect the user device.

Comment: I had  a look but how do I check the screen size?

Comment: You can handle the screen size using the media queries in your css.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use counter0 instead of counter in your first if.
This is because counter0 starts with 0 and counter starts with 1.
So a new row div tag is opened at 0, 4, 8.
And a created row div tag is closed at 3, 7, 11.